# How to install postgres-9.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, postgresql-9.1, aptitude

Many months ago, I installed postgres 8.4 using the following command:

```
$ sudo aptitude install postgresql-8.4 postgresql-client postgresql-contrib
```

Now I am trying to upgrade to 9.1.

```
$ sudo aptitude install postgresql-9.1
```

There apparently is no package that matches 9.1 But it does appear to exist for apt-get. Do I have to go with apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you out:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/upgrading.html

---

or else you can follow these steps:

As root:

```
su - postgres
pg_dumpall > dump.sql
exit
cp ~postgres/dump.sql /root/
```

Now you can safely remove the postgresql-8.4 and install postgresql-9.1:

```
aptitude purge postgresql-8.4
aptitude install postgresql-9.1
```

Next check the postgresql configuration in /etc/postgresql/9.1/main. If you make any changes, make sure to restart postgres with /etc/init.d/postgresql restart.

Postgresql 9.1 is now up and running, let's import our data back into it.

```
su - postgres
psql < dump.sql
```

That's all. You're now fully upgraded to PostgreSQL 9.1

edit:

similar question was asked here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/66194/how-do-i-migrate-my-postgres-data-from-8-4-to-9-1

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For some reason, I didn't see the reply notification until now.

Comment: This does not work for me, the postgres-9.1 package is just not found by Aptitude. I am running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS Server. I already ran aptitude update.